# Excel: automatically fill cells according to the input value using function

Tags: excel

The user inputs a value such as 3.
And I need to fill `C1` to `C3`,3 cells.
If the input value is 5, I need to fill `C1` to `C5`, 5 cells.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your value in **C1**.

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF($C$1>=ROW(),$C$1,"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Whatever you place in **C1** will be replicate that number of times in the cells below.

**EDIT#1:**

If you want the *repetition factor* in **C1** and the *repeated data* in **A1**, then in **C2** enter:

```
=IF($C$1>=ROW()-1,$A$1,"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: What if I want to fill with different value instead of all '3'. And say that my input value is stored in A1

Comment: @KengoTokukawa  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

Use vba. Lets say the input is A1. We would simply do this:

```
Sub Kengo()
If cells(1, "A") = 3 Then
     cells (1, "C") = "Something here3"
     cells (2, "C") = "Something here3"
     cells (3, "C") = "Something here3"
ElseIf cells(1, "A") = 5 Then
     cells (1, "C") = "Something here5"
     cells (2, "C") = "Something here5"
     cells (3, "C") = "Something here5"
     cells (4, "C") = "Something here5"
     cells (5, "C") = "Something here5"
EndIf

End Sub
```